# attachRoutePatternMatched() and attachMatched() called multiple times at every navigation

Tags: sapui5

I would like to fire an event every time I switch between the views in UI5.
To avoid a code duplication, I define an `attachRoutePatternMatched()` inside of a `BaseController`, which all views' controllers are base on:

```js
onInit() {

    const router = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();

    router.attachRoutePatternMatched((event) => {

        this.onViewSwitch(event);

    }, this);

},

onViewSwitch(event) {

    console.log("Bingo, a view switch occurred!");

}
```

It works but the problem is that `onViewSwitch()` is called several times, e.g., if I put a breakpoint, then I reach this function multiple times although just a single navigation made within the [`SideNavigation`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.tnt.SideNavigation/sample/sap.tnt.sample.SideNavigation) inside of `tnt:sideContent` component.

I also tried replacing `attachRoutePatternMatched()` with `attachMatched()` and providing the specific view name:

```js
router.getRoute("wantedView").attachMatched((event) => {

    this.onViewSwitch(event);

}, this);
```

But still at every navigation a breakpoint inside of `onViewSwitch()` is reached about 5 times.

What I don't get, why and where `onViewSwitch()` is called so much times?

**Update:**

Moving `attachRoutePatternMatched()` from `BaseController`'s `onInit()` to the `onInit()` of the `rootView`'s controller solves the issue but I'm still curious to know why `onViewSwitch()` is called multiple times being defined in `BaseController`'s `onInit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much already answered your question in the latest update.

The `onInit` is called once for every view. In other words, even though you code it once, there is a `onInit` for every view.

Everytime the `onInit` the callback, you create a local callback function.

```
() => {
 this.onViewSwitch(event);
}
```

So in the end, once the event happens, all previously registered callbacks are called. So, you have many callbacks doing pretty much the same thing on the occurence of the event - which might led to odd behaviors like the app gettings slower and slower depending on what you are doing on the callback.

Notice that the event itself in your scenario is not the problem. However, keep in mind that some events can be found both in the `Router` class and in the `Route` class and their behavior is different as the first is valid for any route and the later is only valid to the route being used when calling the `attach` function.

Finally, consider doing your logic inside the `Component.js` as the `Router` is probably declared there unless you are doing changing the basic structure of your app. You can register the callback for any event of the `Router` inside the `onInit` of the `Component`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, regarding callbacks, I've expected that `onViewSwitch` of `BaseController` will be called just once within the instance of the specific view (where the event has occurred) and not multiple times. Regarding _"can be found both in the `Router` class and in the `Router`"_, I assume there is a typo here? Yes `Router` is defined in `Component.js`, I'll export `onViewSwitch` there. I have a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236972/how-to-interrupt-and-change-a-routing-navigation-in-ui5) regarding the navigation, could you, please, have a look?