# How to override the routing and redirect to another view in UI5?

Tags: sapui5

Given the simplified sample app based on [Shop Administration Tool](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/tnt/demokit/toolpageapp/webapp/index.html). When navigating with the sidebar between the views, I just show different views, e.g. View #1, View #2, etc. These views are standalone views, each of them has its own XML-template and JS-controller.

Now, I want to add a permission check for each view and if a user has no permission, then he should be redirected to the main view instead of the desired view.

I've implemented a pre-navigation check:

```js
router.attachRoutePatternMatched(async (event) => {

    const targetView = event.getParameters().view.getProperty("viewName");

    const isPermitttedToSeeView = await this.checkUserPermission(targetView);

    if (!isPermitttedToSeeView) {

        MessageToast.show("Sorry, you don't have permissions.");

        router.navTo("mainView");

    }

}, this);
```

This code works but the problem is that in case of no permissions user firstly sees a `MessageToast` message (OK), then is redirected to the forbidden view (bad), and then immediately redirected to the `mainView` view (OK).

I've tried to use [`attachBeforeRouteMatched`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Router#methods/attachBeforeRouteMatched) instead, hoping that in this case the routing is not performed yet and I can redirect a user if needed and user will not see the forbidden view. But not, I still see the forbidden view for a second and then I'm redirected to the `mainView`.

How can I prevent a redirection to the forbidden view and send the user directly to the `mainView` view? In other words, how can I alter a routing navigation pipeline?

Comment: Note that authorization handling needs to be managed by the server-side https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f3d8706f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070

Comment: On a server side I control the data response, so unauthorized person will not get a data. The problem is with a client-side, I would like to provide a smooth UX.

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad to answer since it depends on how the views are structured. Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/59091125/5846045 help?

Comment: To make the UX smooth I would look for a way to present users with the information and functions they need, but nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible workaround is to use a «hard» redirect instead of routing:

```js
mLibrary.URLHelper.redirect("%desiredURL%", false);
```

Where `mLibrary` is defined in `sap.ui.define` via `"sap/m/library"`.

This will drop any ongoing routing and will force (in terms of UX, not in terms of security) user to be redirected to the desired URL.

Perhaps, it's not the optimal solution from the performance point of view, since it might lead to unwanted rendering but that's the only way I found to prevent user from being routed to undesired view.